# Is it too early to try LibreSSL?

Tags: freebsd, openssl

I've been somewhat following the development and recent release of [LibreSSL](http://www.libressl.org) and coincidentally I have a new FreeBSD web server that I've been configuring for my personal/hobbyist projects recently. I'm still fairly n00bish about sysadmin and heavy Unix stuff, though.

I see that there's a `security/libressl` port now. If I, a mere sysadmin mortal, were to install it, would I be able to configure Nginx to use it without much more stress than it takes to use OpenSSL (as I've successfully set up a couple of times in the past)?

What about other ports which have come to expect OpenSSL? For example, when I go to configure `databases/mariadb55-server`, I get an option to have it use OpenSSL, but not LibreSSL. If I install LibreSSL, will its libraries be seen and used as OpenSSL, or do I have to wait for the MariaDB port to be updated to explicitly support LibreSSL?

I guess the broader question is, how interchangeable is LibreSSL with OpenSSL from the perspective of an amateur sysadmin at this point? Should I hold off until LibreSSL is more widely used and expected?

Comment: You specifically asked about the status of LibreSSL on FreeBSD: Bob Beck, the director of the OpenBSD foundation and member of the LibreSSL team, wrote in to this week's [BSDnow podcast](http://bsdnow.tv) in order to point out that there are serious problems with FreeBSD's native random number generator in libc, see [here](http://slexy.org/view/s21Nmg3Jrk) for the full message. Rumour has it that a proposed fix by Ted Unangst is under review by the security team, but nothing seems to have gone into the tree yet. The [LibreSSL homepage](http://libressl.org) also warns about these issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your question whether LibreSSL is intended to be a drop-in replacement for OpenSSL? If so, **yes**. This is explicitly the intention stated by the developers. One point of the current release is to ensure that goal by letting the people responsible for binary packages and source repositories test it. There are a few problems still, but most of them are minor: here is a good blog post about a rather successful experiment [LibreSSL on Gentoo](https://blog.hboeck.de/archives/851-LibreSSL-on-Gentoo.html) by Hanno Boeck.

On the other hand, your question could also be interpreted as "Is LibreSSL production ready"?

The answer is: **No, it isn't**. Not even OpenBSD-current (the development branch) currently links against LibreSSL by default...

It is to be expected that many more problem reports such as [Only a few days old, OpenSSL fork LibreSSL is declared “unsafe for Linux”](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/07/only-a-few-days-old-openssl-fork-libressl-is-declared-unsafe-for-linux/) will hit the tech-news sites over the next days and weeks. These problems will surely be addressed and sorted out over the next few months. Keep in mind that the fork is only three months old and it's a *huge* and *complex* code base.

I'm not allowed to post more links than two, but it is quite easy to find various blog posts, problem reports, and so on by Googling a little. Read the mailing lists of the developers of your distro to have reliable first-hand information on the state of the affairs, and don't buy too much into all the hype that is currently going on.

Take away from this what you wish, but I wouldn't trust LibreSSL too much at this early point in the development process, let alone would I put it into production.

Comment: I don't think that Ars article is really fair because it assumes certain ridiculous circumstances, and, while LibreSSL should definitely still work in those cases, OpenSSL had a lot of cases of behaving badly in those sorts of very specific edge cases too. That being said, your other points are well taken - I'll stick with OpenSSL for now and reconsider things further down the road (maybe once OpenBSD ships with it).

Comment: **This answer is out of date. [OpenBSD has used LibreSSL since 5.6 released Nov 1, 2014.](http://www.openbsd.org/56.html)**

Answer (score 1):

From what I see they have not changed the library and binary names. So every port that sets `USE_OPENSSL` should also work with libressl if you define `WITH_OPENSSL_PORT` in your `make.conf`

Binary packages will still use the base system's openssl.